# What is the process to fix track listing error on Spotify that is also wrong on the CD?

Tags: spotify, music-management, music-streaming

I've just been listening to [The Complete John Cage Edition Volume 18: The Choral Works 1](http://open.spotify.com/album/2aapagP1mFB9CLB8S6JJ%E2%80%8B5C) but the track listing is wrong. (N.B. I'm not a Cage genius, but a new twitter friend is and pointed this out to me). The CD comes from a label called Mode and the track listing is also [wrong on the CD](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Complete-John-Cage-Edition%E2%80%8B-Volume/dp/B007TZ3UUQ/qid=1354549398) so it's not just a Spotify DB thing. What database do Spotify use for their track listings and what is the correct process for getting it corrected when there is an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this [Reporting Incorrect Track Info](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Music-Chat-Social/Reporting-Incorrect-Track-Info/td-p/25291) forum thread, their Contact Form has to be used to inform them of any errors in their listing.

You might also want to keep an eye on the [Way to notify Spotify of incorrect metadata - wrong titles, artists, track name  etc.](http://community.spotify.com/t5/ideas/v2/ideapage/blog-id/ideaexchange/article-id/105) thread for updates.